# how to improve resized image quality in Internet explore 9/10 and FF

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

The image quality is disturbed when I resize the image.
here is the code

```
<img height="60px" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/3/3/4/1195445190322000997molumen_red_round_error_warning_icon.svg.med.png" alt="logo" />
```

how to improve it in IE and FF?
http://jsfiddle.net/CdktR/1/

Answer (score 1):

Resizing in the browser is notoriously unreliable (although some browsers, like Chrome, handle this better than others). You can affect it slightly by adding this to your CSS:

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; -moz-image-rendering: crisp-edges; }
```

But by far the best option is to supply the webpage with a version of the image that's suitably sized. It's a pain if you want to update the image later on, as you'll need to update multiple files, but the only other option I can think of is to use SVGs.

You can check [browser support for SVGs here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img); the short version is unless you're targeting IE8 and below, you should be OK.

Comment: if you check the jsfiddle, the problem is only in IE9 and IE10

Comment: Then I'd recommend using SVGs, with a (resized) image fallback for IE 8 and below.

Comment: same crisped result using svg

Comment: Then you'll need to use a resized graphic.

Comment: image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; must be -moz-image-rendering: crisp-edges;

Answer (score 0):

mozilla has some pretty good stuff regarding this topic. you probably want to use image-rendering property and -ms-interpolation-mode depending on what you are going for exactly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering